# An explanation for Refs outputting the current updated state

Tags: reactjs

When I'm using state, e.g. useState, I can access when the state changes with useEffect as follows:

```
const[searchText, setSearchText]=useState("");
................
useEffect(()=>{
    console.log(searchText) // THIS PRINTS OUT THE CORRECT UPDATED VALUE
},[searchText])
```

I understand this concept fully. However there are situations where I need updated state but cannot use an useEffect hook. I've found this works:

```
const[searchResults, setSearchResults]=useState();
const searchresultRef=useRef();
..........
useEffect(()=>{ 
    searchresultRef.current=searchResults;
},[searchResults])

..........

const SomeFunction=(e)=>{
    console.log(searchresultRef.current) // THIS PRINTS OUT THE CORRECT UPDATED VALUE
    console.log(searchResults) // THIS PRINTS OUT THE UNDEFINED
}
```

After some testing I found out refs works this way with useState and useReducer to give the current updated value in functions however I don't understand why. Could someone give me an explanation as to why the second piece of code works?

Comment: Can you add to your question why you expect it to fail ? (I do have an idea, but don't want to answer the wrong question. I assume you wonder why `searchResults` is undefined but `searchresultRef` is defined)

Comment: Yes I'm wondering why searchresultRef is storing the updated value contained in searchResults useState. I've tried searching but not finding any suitable explanation

Answer (score 1):

The variable from `useState()` is a new variable on each render.

A function might capture the previous value of a state. The function would only see the new state if the function is also created anew *(It is not visible in your example when and how the function is created)*.

A reference from `useRef()` will always be the same object on each render. The reason for using the extra `current` property is to be able to keep the object reference identical.

Consider this example:

```
let fakeUseState = 'first';
let fakeUseRef = { current: 'first' };

const f = function(){

    let state = fakeUseState;
    let ref = fakeUseRef;

    setTimeout( function(){
        console.log( 'state:', state );
        console.log( 'ref.current:', ref.current );
    }, 500 );

    fakeUseState = 'next';       // <-- `fakeUseState` is a completely new identity, different to `state`.
    fakeUseRef.current = 'next'; // <-- `fakeUseRef` is still the same object, and the same as ref.
};

f();
```